# Перевод слова 'bastard' на русский язык

Tags: перевод, лексикон

Слово bastard в значении 4 не ругательное.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bastard

Три вопроса:

- Как его в этом случае перевести на русский язык?
- Можно ли с таким словом обращаться к девушке или только к мужчине?
- В предожении "You won't let me look into the box, you bastard" воспринимается ли это слово как ругательное или неприличное? Сравните с, например, "you won't let me look into the box, you strict person", например, где выражается отношение приличным образом.

Comment: Кхм... По-моему, здесь не поняли, что @Sveta хотела спросить. (И это неудивительно, так как вопрос неудачно сформулирован). Я перечитал несколько раз, и мне кажется что вопрос об употреблении слова "bastard" **в английском языке**. (Что, по мнению многих, здесь off-topic). А фразу `Как его в этом случае перевести на русский язык?` нужно понимать как "Что оно в этом случае значит?", "Как его в этом случае понимать?" Мне нередко задают такой вопрос, и я уже немного привык, что для многих людей "понять" = "перевести на русский". И, соответственно, остальные вопросы тоже об употреблении в английск

Answer (score 4):

Слово `bastard`, как и дословный перевод - `ублюдок`, абсолютно приличное. Другое дело, что оно оскорбительное.

В приведённом примере оно используется не "приличным образом", а в шутку. То бишь грубое, оскорбительное слово используется иронически, в положительном контексте
Таким же убразом в английском часто используется `son of a bitch` и эвфемизм `son of a gun` (эвфемизм всегда используется в положительно контексте).

Естественно, что `ублюдок` в шутку не может использоваться.
А вот `сукин сын` - вполне. `Сукина дочь` используется значительно реже, в любом конексте. Ещё варианты - `урод/уродка` или `засранец/засранка`, но мне кажется, что `сукин сын` более нейтральный вариант. Цитата "`Ай да Пушкин! Ай да сукин сын!`" будет знакома большинству русскоговорящих.

Comment: Ну так, к слову, не про конкретный случай, но bastard дословно переводится как бастард. Бастард это ребёнок неравнородных родителей, скажем один из родителей король, а другой простой дворянин. Ребёнок будет бастардом королевской крови (и дворянином, кстати). Ничего в этом не будет оскобительного, наоборот, для ребёнка остаётся даже небольшой шанс занять трон.

А ублюдок это оскобительная форма для ребёнка, которого зачали в результате изнасилования ("блуд").

Answer (score 1):

В приведённом предложении, где слово звучит оскорбительно, потому что выражает неудовольствие, пусть даже в шутку, его можно было бы перевести и словом **`козёл`**, которое для женщины, разумеется, не годится, **`козлиха`** - уж черезчур сниженный вариант. Правда мне не приходилось сталкиваться с употреблением **bastard** по отношению к женщине.
Или **`гад (такой)`**, а для женщины **`гадина (такая)`**, или **`свинья`**, которое универсально, но в мужском роде может иметь форму **`свин(тус)`**

В значении 4. в статье коннотация несколько иная, чем в примере. Там слово звучит "любя" (affectionate), и для вариантов оттуда, думаю, нельзя подобрать единого перевода.

lucky bastard - счастливчик, везунчик
poor bastard - бедняжка, бедолага, бедненький
Get over here, you old bastard! - Хромай сюда, старый (ты) хрыч/старикашка!

Answer (score 1):

1) В четвертом значении по приведенной ссылке на википедию имеем: "(often humorous) A man, a fellow, a male friend." Ну и переведите, как обычно на русском называют приятеля в шутку по-спортивному (т.е. с вызовом и колкостью, которые незнакомый человек воспримет как оскорбление).

Например:

- Говнюк, засранец
- Старик, клюшка, развалина, старина
- Чувак, поц
- Скотина, чёрт

Или возьмите какой-нибудь перевод для других прозвищ типа lad, fish, chap, fellow (это будет нейтральнее и безопаснее).

Кстати, для современной аудитории (на вскидку, от 1995 года рождения) собственно "ублюдок" уже является известной заимствованной идиомой в этом четвертом значении. Молодые люди часто используют словосочетания "больной ублюдок" (в смысле неудачливый, непонятный, сумасшедший или непредсказуемый), "счастливый ублюдок".

2) Соответственно, такое обращение к девушке совершенно неуместно по лексической причине - в словаре явно указан применяемый пол; морально-этический аспект - второстепенный.

Однако можно представить ситуацию, в которой в некоем обществе к девушке показательно относятся, как к мужчине. Например, положительно, чтобы выразить равенство и доверие ("она - свой в доску парень"), или отрицательно, чтобы подчеркнуть мужеподобность ("она похожа на боксера в сверхтяжелом весе"). Тогда обращение bastard хотя бы обретает *логический смысл* в контексте. О моральной допустимости такого обращения к девушке см. ниже п.3 и ответ @AR.

3) Из одного предложения невозможно понять, будет ли считаться обращение bastard неприличным или ругательным. Нужно установить контекст. Как давно знакомы говорящие друг с другом, какова тема разговора, как развиваются их отношения, есть ли свидетели, каковы их социальные статусы и разница в статусе между ними и т.д.

@AR. справедливо указывает, что слово является *приличным* - потому что у него есть конкретное исходное значение. В беседе, где необходимо обсудить буквальное значение (происхождение ребенка), оно приличное. Но в вашем примере, скорее всего, оно неприличное (как минимум - неформальное), потому что вряд ли в кратком прямом обращении ("эй ты, ублюдок") используется буквальное значение - предложение теряет смысл. Скорее всего, говорящий пытается обидеть адресата, а это является *нарушением приличий*. Есть приличные слова, которые можно использовать неприличным образом. Например, за обедом неприлично обсуждать тему физиологических отправлений и употреблять приличное слово "фекалии".

Степень "ругательности" определить без контекста гораздо сложнее. Я думаю, здесь - это ругательство, т.к. в предложении 2 раза используется местоимение (you). В начале предложения оно стоит к месту, а вот второе употребление вместе с bastard - явное ударение. Говорящий, похоже, испытывает стресс. Возможно шутит, чтобы скрыть стресс. В любом случае, такое ударение - признак неформальной речи.

Но можно представить ситуацию, при которой говорящий - простолюдин, а адресат - бастард; тогда говорящий имеет все основания завидовать статусу бастарда (впрочем, даже в этой ситуации можно использовать обращение "бастард" как ругательство, например, чтобы унизить адресата при свидетелях, имеющих чистое происхождение).

Чтобы понять проблематику употребления bastard, попробуйте в случайные фразы с обращением вставлять какой-нибудь термин, обозначающий происхождение/статус человека, например "холоп", "барин", "вельможа", "раб". Если вам покажется, что в контексте результат будет неуместным, оскорбительным - это ругательство. Если результат будет ироничным - это не совсем приличная шутка.